# среда разработки NetBeans для с++ выдает ошибку error 2

Tags: c++, netbeans

установила NetBenas, все средства Cygwin(g++,make,gdb) установила. компилирую код выдает ошибку Error2(в интернете пишут что это дважды определили main, хотя main у меня один). Файл я создала в "Исходных файлах" проекта1, все правильно же? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Вот сама ошибка:

```
cd 'C:\Users\Leila\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Leila/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Leila/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o newfile.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:6:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from newfile.cpp:1:
/usr/include/sys/reent.h:14:10: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stddef.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:68: build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/newfile.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Leila/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Leila/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 1s)
```

Comment: Зачем в 2019 году мог понадобиться Cygwin и заброшенный NetBeans?

Comment: бесплатная среда разработки

Comment: Попробуйте сначала разобраться с отсутствующим файлом stddef.h

Comment: уже пробовала, та же ошибка

Comment: Возможно, но хотя бы от этой ошибки имеет смысл избавиться :)

Comment: Поставьте себе Visual Studio

Comment: мне там лицензию надо купить)

Comment: У них уже 100 лет есть бесплатный вариант для персонального использования.